# Is this even possible? Creating variables, getting input and passing it from main to a class in Java

Tags: java, class

So I've come across an issue on an assignment and I would like to know if what I'm trying to do is even possible in Java. My professor wants me to pass a variable from the main method into a class if that makes sense.

Here is the code that we have to include in our main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter the first complex number: ");
 double a = input.nextDouble();
 double b = input.nextDouble();
 Complex c1 = new Complex(a, b);

 System.out.print("Enter the second complex number: ");
 double c = input.nextDouble();
 double d = input.nextDouble();
 Complex c2 = new Complex(c, d);
 System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " + " + "(" + c2 + ")" +
" = " + c1.add(c2));
 System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " - " + "(" + c2 + ")" +
" = " + c1.subtract(c2));
 System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " * " + "(" + c2 + ")" +
" = " + c1.multiply(c2));
 System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " / " + "(" + c2 + ")" +
" = " + c1.divide(c2));
System.out.println("|" + c1 + "| = " + c1.abs());
Complex c3 = (Complex)c1.clone();
System.out.println(c1 == c3);
System.out.println(c3.getRealPart());
System.out.println(c3.getImaginaryPart());
 }
}
```

Here is what I have:

```
package complexnumproj;

//Imports scanner class for getting input
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
Documentation Information
-----------------------------
Author: Landon Whitworth
Date:
Purpose:
 */
public class ComplexNumProj {
        static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a;
        double b;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
        Test Code Given By Instructor
        */
        System.out.print("Enter the first complex number: ");
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        double b = input.nextDouble();
        Complex c1 = new Complex(a, b);

        System.out.print("Enter the second complex number: ");
        double c = input.nextDouble();
        double d = input.nextDouble();
        Complex c2 = new Complex(c, d);
        System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " + " + "(" + c2 + ")" +
        " = " + c1.add(c2));
         System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " - " + "(" + c2 + ")" +
        " = " + c1.subtract(c2));
        System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " * " + "(" + c2 + ")" +
        " = " + c1.multiply(c2));
        System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " / " + "(" + c2 + ")" +
        " = " + c1.divide(c2));
        System.out.println("|" + c1 + "| = " + c1.abs());
        Complex c3 = (Complex)c1.clone();
        System.out.println(c1 == c3);
        System.out.println(c3.getRealPart());
        System.out.println(c3.getImaginaryPart());
    }

    public class Complex implements Cloneable{
        /*
        Class Must have following:
        ---------------------------------
        Methods
        ---------------------------------
        - add()
        - subtract()
        - multiply()
        - divide()
        - abs()
        - getRealPart()
        - getImaginaryPart()
        - toString()
        -----------------------------------
        Constructors
        ------------------------------------
        - Complex()
        - Complex(a,b)
        - Complex (a)

        -------------------------------------
        Variables
        -------------------------------------
        */


        //CONSTRUCTORS

        public Complex() {
        }

        public Complex(double a) {

        }

        public Complex(double a, double b) {

        }

        private void getA(){

        }

        //METHODS
        public void getInputForAB(){

        }

        public void getInputForCD(){

        }
        public void add(){
         //a+bi+c +di=(a+c)+(b+d)i
        }

        public void subtract(){

        }

        public void multiply(){

        }

        public void divide(){

        }

        public void abs(){

        }
    }
}
```

I know my code is riddled with errors (mostly because I am not done yet) but the issue I have come across while working on it is that there are no instance variables. I'm assuming that I am supposed to somehow pass the inputs to the Complex class but I have no clue how to do that. I'm only coming here because I've run out of options and ideas on what I'm expected to do and have consulted notes and the textbook. The major thing that is preventing me from continuing is an error on line 25 "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" and when I try to make it static it tells me that I can't.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "*I'm only coming here because I've run out of options*" - Have you asked your professor? --- "*the issue I have come across while working on it is that there are no instance variables.*" - There are instance variables, but within `ComplexNumProj`. One could make it work with those variables, but this seems very hacky and unclean to me. Maybe it's a typo in the exercise text? --- "*The major thing that is preventing me from continuing is an error on line 25*" - What line is line 25?

Comment: @Turing85 No, I'll ask the proffessor. Line 25 is: 
` Complex c1 = new Complex(a, b);`
 That is what is giving me the most issues

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add this information. The following is just guessing on my part since I do not know the exact exercise text: As-is, I would say that instance variables `a` and `b` in class `ComplexNumProj` are a typo and should be in class `Complex`. Even if it is not a typo, I see no restriction to prevent you from adding attributes to class `Complex`. If both classes are in one file, you will have trouble with the implementation, since the inner class is bound to instances of the outer class (and there is no instance of the inner class...).

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class Complex {
    private final double re;   // the real part
    private final double im;   // the imaginary part

    public Complex() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public Complex(double re) {
        this(re, 0);
    }

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    public Complex add(Complex b) {
        return new Complex(re + b.re, im + b.im);
    }

    public Complex subtract(Complex b) {
        return new Complex(re - b.re, im - b.im);
    }

    public Complex multiply(Complex b) {
        return new Complex(re * b.re - im * b.im, re * b.im + im * b.re);
    }

    public Complex reciprocal() {
        double scale = re * re + im * im;
        return new Complex(re / scale, -im / scale);
    }

    public Complex divide(Complex b) {
        return multiply(b.reciprocal());
    }

    public double abs() {
        return Math.hypot(re, im);
    }

    public double getRealPart() {
        return re;
    }

    public double getImaginaryPart() {
        return im;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (im == 0)
            return String.valueOf(re);
        if (re == 0)
            return im + "i";
        if (im < 0)
            return re + " - " + -im + 'i';
        return re + " + " + im + 'i';
    }
}
```

---

**Demo**

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.print("Enter the first complex number: ");
    Complex c1 = new Complex(scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Enter the second complex number: ");
    Complex c2 = new Complex(scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble());

    System.out.format("(%s) + (%s) = (%s)\n", c1, c2, c1.add(c2));
    System.out.format("(%s) - (%s) = (%s)\n", c1, c2, c1.subtract(c2));
    System.out.format("(%s) * (%s) = (%s)\n", c1, c2, c1.multiply(c2));
    System.out.format("(%s) / (%s) = (%s)\n", c1, c2, c1.divide(c2));
    System.out.format("|%s| = %s\n", c1, c1.abs());
    System.out.format("(%s).real= %s\n", c1, c1.getRealPart());
    System.out.format("(%s).imaginary = %s\n", c1, c1.getImaginaryPart());
}
```

---

**Output**

```
Enter the first complex number: 3
2
Enter the second complex number: -9
-2
(3.0 + 2.0i) + (-9.0 - 2.0i) = (-6.0)
(3.0 + 2.0i) - (-9.0 - 2.0i) = (12.0 + 4.0i)
(3.0 + 2.0i) * (-9.0 - 2.0i) = (-23.0 - 24.0i)
(3.0 + 2.0i) / (-9.0 - 2.0i) = (-0.36470588235294116 - 0.1411764705882353i)
|3.0 + 2.0i| = 3.605551275463989
(3.0 + 2.0i).real= 3.0
(3.0 + 2.0i).imaginary = 2.0
```